# How to print memory addresses in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Say I have a variable:

```
let a = ref 3 in magic_code
```

Magic_code should print the address in memory that is stored in `a`. Is there something like that? I googled this but nothing came up...

Comment: You can't do this in the safe part of OCaml. Also, addresses of things change all the time due to garbage collection. Why do you want to know the address?

Comment: I see. For debugging purposes.

Comment: @bigollo: You can see if two variables point to the same thing by using `==` and `!=`. Other than that, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I guess you have to appreciate the abstraction of ocaml.

Comment: If you don't want to give up despite the above pronouncements, learn about the `Obj` module. If you're desperate to use it for debugging, setting a large heap may help for not having the GC kick in.

Comment: *But*, the fact that you need to debug the use of `ref`s means that you're doing it wrong, style-of-programming-wise. It's OK to use mutability as long as it is local and/or closely models the logic of your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```ml
    let a = ref 3 in 
    let address = 2*(Obj.magic a) in
    Printf.printf "%d" address;;
```

OCaml distinguishes between heap pointers and integers using the least significant bit of a word, 0 for pointers and 1 for integers (see this [chapter](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html) in Real World OCaml).

`Obj.magic` is a function of type `'a -> 'b` that lets you bypass typing (i.e. arbitrarily "cast"). If you force OCaml to interpret the reference as an `int` by unsafely casting it via `Obj.magic`, the value you get is the address shifted right by one bit. To obtain the actual memory address, you need to shift it back left by 1 bit, i.e. double the value.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596236/2361830).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think that code will interpret the value as an OCaml int (shifted one bit left), so you'll need to double it to recover the actual pointer. And, obviously, this is a huge and unreliable hack, only useful in emergencies for debugging.

Comment: `Obj.magic`, `Obj.repr`, `Obj.obj` are all implemented as identity functions. They only differences are their type. `Obj.magic` is already a function from any type to any type. So an `Obj.repr` is unnecessary.

Comment: Multiplying it by 2 will lose the most significant bit of the address