# How can I check two "pointers" meet each other when going through a list?

Tags: ocaml

For example, I have a list `[1; 2; 1; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5; 6; 8;...]`. The list has duplicate elements.

Then we go through the list by two **virtual** pointers.

One pointer `a` goes from the beginning and has speed of `2`.

The other pointer `b` goes from somewhere in the middle of list and has speed of `1`.

So how can I check whether `a` meeting with `b`?

---

For example:

`a` starts from `[1; 2; 1; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5; 6; 8;...]`

`b` starts from index `1`, which is `[2; 1; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5; 6; 8;...]`

So after one time move, both `a` and `b` will arrive at index `2` and they meet.

How can I check whether meet or not by the element only, **without info of index**?

We can just compare the value of the two elements, as there might be duplicates inside.

---

In term of code:

```
let l = [1; 2; 1; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5; 6; 8;...]

let find_middle_start l n = 
  let rec aux i = function
    | [] -> []
    | _::tl when i >= n -> tl
    | _::tl -> aux (i+1) tl
  in
  aux 0 l

let parallel_travel l =
  Random.self_init();
  let b_start = find_middle_start l (Random.int (List.length l)) in
  let rec go = function
    | [], _::_ | _::_, [] | _::[], _::_ -> print_endline "Never meet"
    | x::x1::xs, y::ys ->
      if check_meet x y then print_endline "Meet"
      else go xs ys
  in
  go l b_start
```

---

How can I implement `check_meet`? i can't just do `x == y` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the *lists*, and compare them by identity (with `==`).

```
| ((_::_::xs) as a)), ((_::ys) as b) ->
  if a == b then ...
  else ...
```

Note that if you are trying to determine whether a list shares a tail with another list, this method is not sufficient (the slow pointer can reach the end before the fast pointer catches up with it).

Comment: But can `==` be trusted? Does it just compare the pysical address? or all values inside?

Comment: For immutable types its meaning is implementation dependent. So it's not strictly usable here in my opinion.

Comment: I admit this is a bit lax, but there is no real alternative (other than the somewhat unsatisfying position of "you should not do that").

Comment: @JeffreyScofield could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You can read my take on physical equality here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590307/whats-the-difference-between-equal-and-identical-in-ocaml/13590433?s=14%7C0.2034#13590433

Comment: @JeffreyScofield from your answer in that post, it seems you were saying that even if I know the two lists are the same thing, `==` may give wrong answer as OCaml might move or split around? I got a bit confused. In my question here and this answer, `a` and `b` are def from the same list, and you say `a==b` may not be trusted?

Comment: Strictly speaking (according to the definitions in `Pervasives`)  you can't depend on pure OCaml values having an identity at all. So you can't depend on `==` giving any particular answer. All you know is that if `a == b` then `a = b`. (Thus it would be perfectly correct to return false always for pure values.) In practice, currently you can use `==` to test identity. It seems wrong to depend on it, at least to me.