# Removing repeated statements from nested conditions in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

As an exercise in class, we are supposed to calculate the entry price for people in a night club, provided their age and gender. The under 25 get 20% off, and Females/NBs get 50% off, stacking **multiplicatively**.

While my code works, it repeats the gender check twice, which is poor form and could cause problems in a more complex application. How can I spare the repetition ?

```ml
(* OCaml Version *)
let entry_price age gender =
    if age < 18 
    then (failwith "Must be over 18 to enter")
    else let price = 12.0 in
      if age <= 25
      then let price = (price *. 0.8) in
        if gender == 'f' || gender == 'x'
        then (price *. 0.5)
        else prix
      else if gender == 'f' || gender == 'x'
        then (price *. 0.5)
        else price;;
```

Here is a Python version that does not repeat itself, thanks to ternary operators : (*Could also be done with non-nested ifs, which Ocaml disallows*)

```py
# Python version
def entry_price(age : int, gender : str):
    if age < 18:
        raise ArgumentError("Must be over 18 to enter")
    return ( 
        12.0
        *(0.8 if (age<25) else 1)
        *(0.5 if gender in ['f', 'x'] else 1)
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pretty much copy the python version:

```
let entry_price age gender =
  if age < 18 
  then failwith "Must be over 18 to enter"
  else
    12.0
    *. (if age < 25 then 0.8 else 1.0) 
    *. (if gender = 'f' || gender = 'x' then 0.5 else 1.0);;
```

There's only a slight difference in the `if` expression syntax, and you need to use the float-specific multiplication operator, `*.`, instead of the int-specific `*`.

Also, to pick a nit, there are no statements in OCaml. Statements are an imperative/procedural construct, ie. do this, then do that. OCaml is an expression-based language, where each expression evaluates to a value. You can still discard the value of an expression, and thereby make it look like a statement, but the compiler will complain unless you are very explicit about discarding it since that is usually a user error.

Comment: I note you used `=` rather than `==` as in the OP's code. Might be worth mentioning and explaining why.

Comment: @Chris is == even valid in ocaml ? We have only seen the single = in class, and I think I remember using == being a syntax error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590307/whats-the-difference-between-equal-and-identical-in-ocaml

Comment: Alright, I guess that works. It still seems very confusing to me that everything has to be a single **expression** which does everything at once, for now it still seems like a contrivance / party trick (everything is technically a one-liner). I guess I’m just very used to OO / Imperative thinking.

Comment: @Chris seems like == in ocaml is like Swift’s === then

Comment: It's a major change in mindset. If you keep practicing, it will click eventually for you.

Answer (score 4):

@glennsl provides a nice direct translation of the Python code to OCaml, but there are other ways we can approach this.

If we create a variant type to describe ages, we can write a `categorize_age` function which will translate a numeric age to a descriptive term we can pattern match on. It also gives us a convenient place in the future to change what ages we use to make these determinations.

Then we can use a `match` on both `age` and `gender` to consider the four possible outcomes:

- Under 18
- Under 25 *and* either `'f'` or `'x'` gender
- 25 or older *and* either `'f'` or `'x'` gender
- Anyone else 18 or older

```
type age_cat = Under_age | Legal | Adult

let categorize_age a = 
  if a < 18 then Under_age
  else if a <= 25 then Legal
  else Adult
        
let entry_price age gender = 
  let price = 12.0 in
  match categorize_age age, gender with  
  | Under_age, _       -> failwith "Must be over 18 to enter"
  | Legal, ('f' | 'x') -> price *. 0.8 *. 0.5 (* or just 0.4  *)
  | Adult, ('f' | 'x') -> price *. 0.5 *. 0.5 (* or just 0.25 *)
  | _                  -> price
```

Looking at the logic here, we actually don't need to specify `Adult, ('f' | 'x')` because we know that we've already matched cases where when `gender` is `'f'` or `'x'`, `age` is either `Under_age` or `Legal`. Thus we can use a wildcard `_` for the pattern: `_, ('f' | 'x')`.

The last pattern is a wildcard because we're matching any case that hasn't already been matched, and those values are not relevant to the outcome, so there's no point in binding name(s) to them.

```
let entry_price age gender = 
  let price = 12.0 in
  match categorize_age age, gender with  
  | Under_age, _       -> failwith "Must be over 18 to enter"
  | Legal, ('f' | 'x') -> price *. 0.8 *. 0.5 (* or just 0.4  *)
  | _,     ('f' | 'x') -> price *. 0.5 *. 0.5 (* or just 0.25 *)
  | _                  -> price
```

Comment: While this is probably worse than @glennsl ‘s solution for this particular example, it does seem more versatile, especially for non-arithmetic applications.

Comment: I think it more directly shows the relationship between the `age` and `gender` inputs to the `entry_price` function, and what they map to.